# wxPython: write SQL command results to outputbox

Tags: textbox, wxpython, self

I'm trying to get back into Python and I'm once again stuck with this problem I've had before of making objects accessible to one another. In this simple example I am displaying a panel with a button and a text box. Clicking on the text box calls a function which queries a database and returns a cursor with the retrieved data. I need to make it so that either the LookupSQL function or the ShowClientData function can write this output, in a loop, to the Text box. The TextBox (outputBox) is unknown to any other functions currently. How do I make it so that the other functions know what it is?

```
import wx
import pypyodbc
conn = pypyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', server='.', database='TheDB', uid='sa', pwd='Pass')


class Audit(wx.Frame):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 

    self.InitUI()

def InitUI(self):    

    panel = wx.Panel(self)

    hbox = wx.BoxSizer()
    sizer = wx.GridSizer(6,1,2,2)

    btn1 = wx.Button(panel, label='Clients')

    outputBox = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.HSCROLL)
    sizer.AddMany([btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6])

    hbox.Add(sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 15)
    hbox.Add(outputBox, 1, wx.EXPAND)


    panel.SetSizer(hbox)

    btn1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ShowClientData)

    self.SetSize((800, 600))
    self.SetTitle('Audit View')
    self.Centre()
    self.Show(True)


def ShowClientData(self, event):
    SQL = 'select * from V_UpdatedClient'
    recursor = lookupSQL(SQL)
    for row in recursor:
        rChange = row[0]
        rItemType = row[1]
        rPK = row[2]
        rItemCode = row[3]
        rFieldName = row[4]
        rOldValue = row[5]
        rNewValue = row[6]
        rUpdateDate = row[7]
        rUserName = row[8]
        print('%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s' % (rChange, rItemType, rPK, rItemCode, rFieldName, rOldValue, rNewValue, rUpdateDate, rUserName))


def lookupSQL(SQLString):       
  cursor = conn.cursor()
  cursor.execute(SQLString)

  return cursor        
  cursor.close()


def main():

  ex = wx.App()
  Audit(None)
  ex.MainLoop()    


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What you are looking for is called [data attributes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects).**

```
self.outputBox = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.HSCROLL)
```

And then within `ShowClientData` you can write

`self.outputBox.AppendText("some text")`

As long as you have that `self` reference, you can access its attributes.

Edit:

When you do the above change, you can't refer to the text box by just `outputBox` anymore, you should instead access it via self:

`hbox.Add(self.outputBox, 1, wx.EXPAND)`

Declaring it as globally is very bad!

Comment: ShowClientData still doesn't recognised it when it's defined and called with self.

NameError: name 'outputBox' is not defined

I tried declaring outputBox as global, and that worked, but I'm not sure it's good practice

Comment: See my edit, you should access `outputBox` via self, so make that change wherever it is used.

Comment: still getting an error

      self.outputBox.WriteText('%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s \n' % (rChange, rItemType, rPK, rItemCode, rFieldName, rOldValue, rNewValue, rUpdateDate, rUserName))
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: ah, OK, because LookupSQL is not defined as a self
adding an extra paramenter (self) to each occurence of the function name does the trick